# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application that use mysql and it work FINE on my desktop.
But when i upload it to my server it shows the next error:

```
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 17:            <assemblies>
Line 18:         <add assembly="MySql.Data.Entity, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 19:         <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
Line 20:                <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/></assemblies>
```

Also get an error help:

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
```